# Why my view is not showing in angular ui-view?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, angularjs, angular-ui-router

I am trying to wireup angularjs and rails. By following https://thinkster.io/angular-rails#angular-routing. I am not able to find out why my views is not showing up. I am getting empty page in browser.

```
**My routes**
angular.module('flapperNews', ['ui.router', 'templates']).config([
'$stateProvider', '$urlRouterProvider', function($stateProvider,
   $urlRouterProvider){
   $stateProvider
      .state('home',{
        url: '/home',
        templateUrl: 'home/_home.html',
        controller: 'MainCtrl',
      resolve: {
      postPromise: ['posts', function(posts){
      return posts.getAll();
     }]
     }
      })
      .state('posts', {
        url: '/posts/{id}',
        templateUrl: 'posts/_posts.html',
        controller: 'PostsCtrl',
      resolve: {
      post: ['$stateParams', 'posts', function($stateParams, posts) {
      return posts.get($stateParams.id);
     }] 
    }
      });
 $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('home');     

 }]);

Application.html.erb page

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>FlapperNews</title>
 <meta charset="utf-8"/>
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

  <%= stylesheet_link_tag 'application', media: 'all' %>
  <%= javascript_include_tag 'application' %>
  <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
  </head>
  <body ng-app="flapperNews">
 <div class="row">
 <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
  <ui-view></ui-view
 </div>
 </div>
 </body>
 </html>

 partial view
<div class="page-header">
  <h1>Flapper News</h1>
</div>

<div ng-repeat="post in posts | orderBy:'-upvotes'">
  <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-thumbs-up"
    ng-click="incrementUpvotes(post)"></span>
  {{post.upvotes}}
  <span style="font-size:20px; margin-left:10px;">
    <a ng-show="post.link" href="{{post.link}}">

      {{post.title}}
    </a>
    <span ng-hide="post.link">
      {{post.title}}
    </span>
  </span>
  <span>
  <a href="#/posts/{{post.id}}">Comments</a>
  </span>
</div>

<form ng-submit="addPost()"
  style="margin-top:30px;">
  <h3>Add a new post</h3>

  <div class="form-group">
    <input type="text"
    class="form-control"
    placeholder="Title"
    ng-model="title"></input>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <input type="text"
    class="form-control"
    placeholder="Link"
    ng-model="link"></input>
  </div>
  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Post</button>
</form>
```

Comment: dev tools console errors?

Comment: you can't render rails partials as angular view pass it into assets or use angular-rails-templates

Comment: i am using angular rails template.

Answer (score 0):

Please change your cdn router url

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui-router/0.2.18/angular-ui-router.js"></script>
```

instead of

```
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui-router/0.2.10/angular-ui-router.js"></script>
```

Comment: I am using the same you have suggested. Still it's not working.

Comment: A little explanation of your solution would be helpful. What's the problem and how does your change solve it?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that the promise which is returned in the resolve part of the state is resolved. That may be a reason why the view is never showing. To check if this is the problem, simply remove the resolve part from the state and try to reload the page.

Comment: I tried that still it's not working. I can see _home.html is getting loaded but it's not showing in <ui-view></ui-view>

Comment: Change  <ui-view></ui-view to  <ui-view></ui-view>. This may be your problem or maybe is a typo

Comment: Try wrap your partial _post.html view in **<script type="text/ng-template" id="posts/_posts.html"></script>**
You should do the same with all views, id in script tag should match templateUrl from the state

Comment: It didn't work. I tried using ng-include just for nav bar. That is also not displaying.  You can see my codes here : https://github.com/sourabh-garg/flapper-news.

Comment: In app.js you should use angular.module('flapperNews', ['ui.router', 'templates', 'Devise']) but when you declare a controller you should use angular.module('flapperNews'). The first one is a setter and the second one is a getter. So change the postCtr and mainCtrl to angular.module('flapperNews').controller('**conroller_name**'....
Because you were using setter module twice, config settings for routing  were deleted